# How can I go about getting a locked question unlocked?

Tags: feature-request, locked-questions

Is there any possible way to *unlock* a locked question? Like, for example, say you seen an old question on Stack Exchange which is locked but they won't unlock it?

Comment: Can you link to said example?

Comment: Are you asking about historical locks, or content dispute locks (or another type of lock)?

Comment: Have you read the lock notice that explains why the question was locked in the first place? Are you sure that this reason no longer applies?

Comment: If you have a good reason for wanting it to be unlocked, you can raise a custom flag and ask a moderator to unlock it. But if you don't give a good reason for why it should be unlocked, your flag will probably be declined.

Answer (score 4):

Yes: become a moderator, and if the question meets the criteria for unlocking, you can unlock it.

There is no way to unlock a question that is available to regular users.

Comment: Many locks are timed, though, and might eventually unlock automatically.